# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n 2i}{(2n+1)z^{2n+1}}$ on squarewith vertices $\pm6\pm6i$?

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition

Can someone explain me how I can check whether the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n 2i}{(2n+1)z^{2n+1}}$ is uniform on the (boundary of) square $A$ with vertices $\pm6\pm6i$?

Comment: By "square", you mean the boundary here, I presume?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes indeed

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I've fixed it.

Comment: Review: Convergence means that if there is a limit L(z) and you pick an  $\epsilon$ there is some N so that |L(z) - $\sum_1^nf(z)| < \epsilon$ for all n > N.  Uniform convergence means that the N does not depend on z. The usual approach is to show the sum is less than the sum for a fixed z; ordinarily we would look at the z that makes the sum the biggest.

Comment: user102815, will you tell us a little bit about your familiarity with complex functions? Are you familiar with Laurent series? Taylor series? The area of convergence of power series? Also, as this is homework, please let us know what you've tried, and what you know of the concepts involved (something like @BettyMock's review, and anything else you know that might apply)

Comment: @JonathanY. I'm familiar with Laurent and Taylor series. Area of convergence is unknown to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we have a series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n 2i}{(2n+1)z^{2n+1}},$$

we can bound the size of the terms from above when we can bound the absolute modulus of $z$ from below.

On the square (boundary/contour) with vertices $\pm 6 \pm 6i$, we know that $\lvert z\rvert \geqslant 6$. Thus we can majorise the series by

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\lvert \frac{(-1)^n 2i}{(2n+1)z^{2n+1}} \right\rvert \leqslant \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2}{(2n+1)6^{2n+1}} < \frac13\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{36^n}$$

and see that the series converges uniformly on the contour. More, we can see that it converges uniformly on $\{ z \in\mathbb{c} : \lvert z\rvert \geqslant r\}$ for *every* $r > 1$ since the analogous computation yields a majorisation by a geometric series with ratio $r^{-2} < 1$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you tell me what ''majorise'' means?

Comment: Bound from above termwise. $a_n$ majorises $b_n$ if $\lvert b_n\rvert \leqslant a_n$ for all $n$. Of course you're only interested in majorisations with finite sum, when pondering convergence of series. If you can find a majorisation that is independent of $z$ and has finite sum, then the series converges uniformly (also known as the Weierstraß M-test).

Answer (score 0):

This is intended as addition to @DanielFischer's answer, which covers the given question. In general, when one considers a Laurent series
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_n(z-z_0)^n,$$
it's well-known (good reference by @Argon [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256777/laurent-series-radius-of-convergence)) that the series converges in annulus $\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid R_1<|z−z_0|<R_2\}$ for some $0\leq R_1,R_2$ and diverges outside the closure of the annulus (naturally, the series might diverge on the entire plane). Convergence on the boundary of the open annulus--or a subset of it--is possible, but not of interest here. As an aside, one can find $R_1,R_2$ based on knowledge of the $a_n$'s, as demonstrated on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series#Convergent_Laurent_series).

Following DanielFischer's arguments, you can see that the series converges *uniformly* on any subannulus, i.e., $$\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid R^\prime_1\leq|z−z_0|\leq R^\prime_2\},$$
for $R_1<R^\prime_1\leq R^\prime_2<R_2$. In fact, as such closed annuli are compact (at least if $R^\prime_2<\infty$), and any compact subset is contained in such an annulus, it's customary to say that Laurent series converge uniformly on compacta. Here, the given square is a compact subset of the region of convergence (namely, $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z|>1\}$, as DanielFischer also showed).